# Magento Cookie expire time doesn't match with the time set

Tags: php, magento, cookies, session-cookies, magento-1.9

I have set in Magento admin

cookie life time = 86400

Time zone = Asia/Kolkata.

But when I check the cookie expiry in Mozilla Firebug,
I see the cookie expiry as 5.30 hour less then the current time access by me.

I have tried to change the UTC time to Asia/Kolkata in 
`app/Mage.php`
`app/etc/config.xml`
But still I am not able to match the cookie expiry time as 24hours from the access time.

Again I am facing another problem, that when I add a product in the cart it shows fine, but when I navigate to another product(continue shopping), the product in the cart disappears.
Can it be related to - timezone mismatch?

Comment: Your cart issue might be due to time mismatch. Check your logs and clear cache

Comment: @urfusion - I have cleared all cache. Browser cache, magento cache. log file is empty. There are some entries in `exception.log`. Also the product added to cart is there in the database, only it is not showing in the cart in the frontend.

Comment: check for your session time too. cart always save data in session. if session time is very low then you might loss products from cart

Comment: @urfusion - okay I think I have missed that. I will take a look from where I can set the session time